# NVD3 Line Plus Bar With Focus Chart only displaying half width of first and last bar

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

This is what it looks like:

[image]

This is what I want it to look like:

[image]

(Created by adding dummy data in the beginning and end, and manually deleting svg paths...)

.forceX() only works for the small focus chart (the bottom one), but not with the main chart. I've been trying to fix it in the source code to no avail.

Comment: did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: I used this as an opportunity to learn JavaScript more properly and messed around quite a lot in the source code. Yes, I do have a working graph (even added some smooth animations!), but the source code is not winning any beauty contests and I've modified some behavior so there's no chance of it being merged upstream...

Comment: @kerryz can you enlighten us?

Comment: this is not a big deal, just push and unshift a dummy value in your values array ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add elements to before and after for each series. For x, use the number before and after the first and last number. For y, use NaN. This will create an extra space before and after the bars.

Answer (score 0):

For the community here is the workaround, adding 1 day in my case as I deal with days (in second in my case), and using NaN as value so that it is not draw on the chart ;) Don't hesitate to ask for more informations :o)

```
  barChart.unshift([minTimestamp - 86400, NaN]);
  lineChart.unshift([minTimestamp - 86400, NaN]);

  barChart.push([maxTimestamp + 86400, NaN]);
  lineChart.push([maxTimestamp + 86400, NaN]);
```